# sending local emails to hotmail issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks, hotmail

I have the following code that causes 'The SMTP host was not specified.'
Any ideas why this happen?
Many thanks

```
var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail@hotmail.co.uk"));
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("atest@test.com");

mailMessage.Subject = "my test subject";
mailMessage.Body = "my test body";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient { EnableSsl = true };
object userState = mailMessage;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

I've tried the following now and it still fails

```
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "password"),
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false
            };

            var mail = new MailMessage("test@example.com", "me@gmail.com", "hello", "there");
            mail.Body = "Hello";
            mail.Subject = "hi";
            client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I'm not sure but, may be you should set your port number as 587

Comment: If it says the SMTP host was not specified, I'll bet you... didn't specify the SMTP host. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx, watch out for the `Host`property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add mailSettings in web.config? Please check the below link by Scott.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Comment: var email = new MailMessage
                    {
                        From = new MailAddress("test@foo.com")
                    };

                email.To.Add(new MailAddress("test@hotmail.co.uk"));
                email.Subject = "This is my subject";
                email.Body = "This is the content";

                var client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Send(email);

Comment: together with 
  <system.web>

    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@foo.com">
        <network host="smtp.live.com" port="25" userName="test@hotmail.co.uk" password="test" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>

Comment: but i still get the host error.  Any suggestions please?  Many thanks

Comment: @JamesRadford if this answered your question please also up vote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not specified the [smtpClient.Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.host.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have defined a server to send through, unless you have done this in your application config.

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp>
                <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

You need to specify your settings rather than the local ones I used in the example above.

Comment: thanks, i've added this config setting although i still get the same problem.

Comment: <system.web>

    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>

Comment: Excellent glad my suggestion has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, 25)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
    EnableSsl = false
};

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, receiver, head, body);
client.Send(mail);
```

You should specify your Smtp Server as shown above.

---

Or you can specify it at web.config file.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network 
       host="server" 
       port="portNumber"
       userName="username"
       password="password" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSL before you send the message

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl=true;
```

Comment: is there a host smtp.live.co.uk? I'm not sure , may be try this one